# Sticky scroll content inside an overflow div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have structure like this, I have fixed footer and header, and all content is scrollable in the middle of those two. I have one div which is central oriented(overflow hidden, scroll bar in inside that area), and inside that div I have split between left and right side, on left side I have vertical list with items, and on hover I show on right side item details, so would be nice to show that details div (fixed height 355px) right after item in left list.

Any suggestion?

here is my code:

```
$('.sd_dish').hover(function(e) {
    var full_id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    var url = $("#url_"+full_id).text();
    $("#dish_photo").attr('src', url);
    if (first_time)
    {
        $('#dish_details_container').fadeIn();
        first_time = false;
    }

    if(e.pageY > 335)
    {
        var ntop = e.pageY - 100;
        $('#dish_details_container').css('top', ntop);
    }
});
```

CSS for that div

```
#dish_details_container{
   z-index:999;
   position:absolute;
   right:10px;
   display:none;
 }
```

first time when use hover an list element on left side list I show that details page and it persists all the time.